# Finding a line with minimum distance among a set of points

Tags: geometry, optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Suppose I have a set of points denoted by $a_i$

I want to minimize this model:

$$\sum_i (w |(x-a_i)|1(x-a_i)+v|x-a_i|1(a_i-x))$$

where 1(x) denotes an indicator function which takes value $1$ if $x>0$ and $0$, otherwise.

I believe this optimization model should have a close form solution. In fact, the solution represents a line that minimizes the weighted distance between this line (i.e., y=x) and a set of points.

Comment: It seems that you minimise the total weighted distance between the point $x$ and points $a_i$ on the real line. In this case you need to find $x$ such that the difference between total weight and total weight on the right is minimal by absolute value. I believe that there is no formula for that.

Comment: That is correct. I simplified the problem by considering only one weight i.e., w instead of w_i and v instead of v_i. Intuitively, the optimal solution should be v/(v+w) average(a_i) but I can not prove it.

Comment: That doesn't seem correct because if you translate all $a_i$ ($a_i\mapsto a_i+\lambda$), the optimal solution is also translated by $\lambda$.

Comment: What are $u$ and $w$ ? Constants ? In this case, you could factorize into : $\sum_i  |(x-a_i)| \underbrace{(w.1(x-a_i)+v.1(a_i-x))}_{f(x)}$ where $f(x)$ can take either the value $v$ or the value $w$... Is it right ?

Comment: Yes. v and w are constant values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the sum like this:
$$
f(x)=\sum_i (w |(x-a_i)|1(x-a_i)+v|x-a_i|1(a_i-x)) = \sum_i b(x-a_i)+c |x-a_i|
$$
with $b=\frac{w-v}{2}$ and $c=\frac{v+w}{2}$. Differentiate with respect to $x$:
$$
f'(x)=\sum_i b + c~\text{sign}(x-a_i)
$$

$f(x)$ is a piecewise-linear function that changes slope at points $a_k$. Thus, its minimum is given by one of them. We need to find a point $x=a_k$ such that the slope of $f'(x)$ is not positive to the left of it and is not negative to the right of it. This condition can be written as
$$
-2c\le Nb+(k-1)c-(N-k)c \le 0
$$
or
$$
0 \le \frac{Nb}{2c} + \frac{2k+1-N}{2} \le 1
$$

Then the answer is $k = \lceil\frac{N-1}{2}+\frac{NB}{2c}\rceil$  and the optimal $x$ is given by $a_k$.

Comment: Very elegant solution. I accepted it.